# Can the phrase "make a death wish" have a double meaning?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I could be wrong because I'm not a native-English speaker but I think the phrase make a death wish can have two meanings:

1. To make/create a wish to die
2. To make/create a wish before or in the process of dying

Are these two definitions accurate? Why or why not?

Like, a birthday wish isn't wanting to have a birthday, but making a wish during a birthday.

Comment: The part 1 in your sentence isn't used that way. *death wish* is used like this: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/death%20wish. The part 2 in your list should be *dying wish* or *last wish*.

Comment: Also, most often, the phrase is "have a death wish", not "make a death wish", usually said to someone doing something reckless, as in "That's really dangerous! Do you have a death wish or something?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question stems from a confusion that I will clear up in this answer. The first part in your two-item list is incorrect because it is not used that way. It should be *to have a death wish*.

In the definition of **death wish** provided by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/death%20wish) and [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/death_wish), the most common suggested use is **to have a death wish**, which was also provided in the comments.

The second part in your list, however, is a different thing entirely.

See **dying wish** at [MERRIAM WEBSTER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dying%20wish), defined as

> the last thing a person wants before dying.